# Организация тегов в бд и запросах

Tags: теги, php, база-данных, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть такая штука тэги, к сообщениям/постам. т.е. есть у нас бд, в которой много постов, и хочется прикрутить к каждому посту тэги. Если тегов много - создавать для каждого отдельный столбик в таблице - думаю не лучший вариант.

Вопрос раз: как хранить теги в бд правильно? в одной ячейке через запятые?

Вопрос два: (исходя из первого ответа) приведите пример запроса к таблице, с поиском определенного тега?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpress называет теги, категории и пр. способы группировки постов волшебным словом [Таксономия](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). Идея такая: посты отдельно, примочки отдельно. Как минимум две доп. таблицы: Теги и Связи.

В Тегах описываете каждый уникальный тег.

```
tag_id    tag_title    tag_count
```

В Связях записываете отношения Поста с Тегом:

```
post_id    tag_id
```

Comment: эммм... т.е. я хочу найти записи с таким то тегом - запрашиваю таблицу с тегами -> нахожу id тега. далее запрашиваю таблицу связей -> нахожу id записей с этим тегом. далее уже запрос к основной таблице по нужным записям. вариант крайне интересный!

Comment: По идее, вы уже знаете id тега, когда щелкаете по его ссылке скажем, в облаке тегов - вы ведь их там пропишите. Запрос должен будет лишь вытащить посты с этим id тега. ПОскольку, всё сплошь индексы - это крайне быстрая операция. Что-то типа

    SELECT posts.* 
    FROM table_posts AS posts
        JOIN table_relations AS rel ON rel.post_id = posts.id
        AND tag_id = 12345

Answer (score 3):

Ну хранить можно и через запятую в одном поле.

Есть вариант хранить для каждой записи отдельную строку для данного тега, но тут тогда много записей в БД, но если их сделать `INDEX` то выборка будет быстрее (работа с числами).

т.е.
есть у нас запись с ID 3 а в БД будет написано для первого и второго случая так

**Первый 1 запись**

```
ID | ID_REC | TAGS

  1|    1   |  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

**Второй много записей**

```
ID | ID_REC | TAGS

 1 |   1    | 1
 2 |   1    | 2
 3 |   1    | 1
 4 |   1    | 2
 5 |   1    | 1    
 6 |   1    | 2
 7 |   1    | 1
 8 |   1    | 2
```

Ну вот так. Можно хранить сериализованным массивом, но не пользовался ни разу таким способом.

Второй будет скорее всего быстрее по поиску и обновлению информации т.к. добавить к записи тег будет просто `INSERT` ну а удалить `DELETE` т.е. не нужно делать **`select`** а потом **`update`**

Comment: объем не указал. виноват. допустим записей оч. много, и тегов тоже. т.е. тегам присваиваем номера, и все же отдельная ячейка для каждого?

Comment: Для второго варианта не нужен ID строки. Индексом должно быть уникальное сочетание  ID_REC,ID_TAG. В противном случае в результате ошибок возможны множественные записи одно и того же тега для одной записи.

Comment: теперь понял. получается, теги в отдельной таблице - и все же номера тегов в отдельных ячейках. так?

Comment: В варианте через запятую будут проблемы с поиском записей по tag_id.