# Как хранить теги к посту?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть таблица постов с полями id, caption, content, date и тд. Каждый пост может содержать несколько тегов(обычные теги для блога). Как хранить теги в БД, чтобы можно было сделать запрос вида: "select * from posts where tag={$tag_name}"?

Comment: Создать отдельную таблицу для тегов и таблицу, где будут два поля: id поста и id тега.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном треде обсуждали схожий вопрос

[Организация тегов в бд и запросах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148204/php-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85)