# Как в БД реализовать прикрепление тегов к материалу?

Tags: postgresql, база-данных

Есть большое количество материала(текстов) к которым прикрепляются теги. Возникает вопрос, как правильно организовать структуру в базе данных, чтобы потом можно было быстро находить похожие материалы по тегам и делать быстрые фильтрации по разным тегам?

База данных используется PostgreSQL.

Comment: как-то так:

    table texts { id, value } -- тексты
    table tags { id, value }` -- отдельно дефайним теги
    table text_tags {text_id, tag_id)} -- привязка текстов к тегам M-M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Самый простой вариант** это традиционная схема "многие-ко-многим". (см. коммент [@jmu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1810))

Есть три таблицы - статьи/тэги/таблицасвязей. Таблицу тэгов при необходимости можно не использовать (если вы не планируете связывать с тэгами какую-либо дополнительную информацию).

Поиск выполняем `IN`-ом с группировкой.

Получаем нормализованную схему, однако быстродействие этого варианта ниже, по сравнению с остальными.

**Второй вариант** - в таблице со статьями дополнительная колонка с тегами, перечисленными через запятую или какой-либо другой разделитель.

Поиск выполняем `LIKE`-ом по полю с тегами.

**Третий вариант** - аналогичен второму, с той разницей что дополнительная колонка является [массивом](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html).

Поиск выполняется с помощью операторов `&&` и `@>` по полю с массивом меток.

Во втором и третьем случае схема данных получается денормализованной, однако поиск выполняется значительно быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

[Тема уже была, поиск рулит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148204/php-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85). Мне, как обычно, магическими силами, был послан ответ с выше.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё есть триграммы.(надо установить соответствующее расширение и создать триграмный индекс на поле value в таблице тегов)
Позволяют индексировать запросы с любым  like
главное, чтобы длинна индексируемой строки была не слишком большой 50-100 символов.
У меня по тестам очень быстро всё работало.
Это как раз подойдёт если я хочу искать подходящие теги и не уверен в написании, а тегов много.